# How to use class type ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, class, arraylist

I am studying the Java and 
I am studying about concept of class type of class

For example, 
in the Print.java

```
public class Print{
    public ArrayList<data> list;
    public Print(){
        list = new ArrayList<data>();
    } 


    public void printIndexList() {
        for (data index : list) {
            System.out.format("\", index.name)
        }

        for (String definition : b.def) {
            System.out.format("%-6s", definition);
        }
    }
```

and In the data.java

```
public class  data{
     public String name
     public ArrayList<String> def;

     public data(){
         def = new ArrayList<String>();
     }
}
```

And, in the `main.java`, 
I have String type `ArrayList` "defmain" and `String` type "mainname"

I would like to add the defmain and mainname in the list  because I need to use printing function in the b.java

What I tried to do way

in the `main.java`, I have created: -

```
Print ia = new ptiny();

Array<Print> mainlist = new Array<Print>();
```

and.. tried to assign value in the list in the `a.java`

```
ia.list = mainlist;
```

however, it didn't really work. 
does anybody know a way to add a string value and an arraylist in the Arraylist which has type "a"?

thanks

Comment: Details of what you are doing exactly where matter for this, so it would be better to present code representing your best attempt, rather than describing it.

Comment: You have `ArrayList<b>` in your `a class`, and you are talking about filling out `ArrayList<a>`, which is not declared anywhere. Please consider re-phrasing your content.

Comment: Why a downvote in this question? This is just lacking a better sentence phrasing, else it is worth to be posted here.

Comment: sorry , i am not sure how to make better expression. I am just beginner of java

Comment: The only person that might need to apologize is the person who (mysteriously) voted down the question.

Comment: Note that by Java conventions, class names should start with **uppercase** letters.

Comment: @RohitJain - If you understand what the OP is asking, please edit the question. I didn't down-vote, but it's easy to understand why somebody would: this question makes no sense.

Comment: it was just example to explain my concern lol.

Comment: @jahroy. If it doesn't make sense to you, please don't bother reading. At least OP have shown some effort. It's not required at SO, that `English` should be a native language for posters. So, its absolutely fine.

Comment: I am reading over and over trying to understand. I have no problem with people who don't speak English and feel that I usually do a pretty good job of figuring out what people mean. This one doesn't make sense. Notice that the answer somehow involves a class named _Index_, which isn't even mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that class names should start with uppercase letters. The following should work:

```
A ia = new A();
B ib = new B();
ib.def.add("Test");
ia.list.add(ib);
ia.printIndexList();
```

Note that I'm not assigning any list. I'm adding elements to lists.

Comment: thanks it was very close answer that I would like ti see. but i eventually figure it out. thanks for help me !! thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can work out the way you're attempting to achieve what you want to do cannot work.

You can't assign a list of a's to a list of b's.

What you can do is iterate over the list of a's you do have:

```
for (a index : list) {
  index.printIndexList();
}
```

Maybe this is not what you want but it's hard to tell from your question.

Another approach is that you can add the contents from all your a's into the single a thus:

```
for (a index : list) {
  ai.list.addAll(index.list);
}
```

Typically in Java class names start with a capital letter so a should be A and b should be B

Answer (score -1):

I just figure it out !! thanks for helping

what I need to do wast

I need to create

```
Print var = new Print();
var.name = "Herry";
var.defintions = somearraylistin;
ArrayList<Print> ls = new ArrayList<Print>();
ls.add(var);
data.list =is;
data.printIndexList();
```

thanks

OMG

it takes almost 3 hours figure it out!!

:)

Comment: Please follow Java Coding Conventions. Your class names should start with `Uppercase` letters. And please use some meaningful class name. `A` and `B` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Where is _b_ defined? What does `b.list= is` mean?

Comment: Rohit Jain how can i change it? can you give me the guideline?  sorry...

Comment: jahroy sorry, b what name of the class. like..  Print var = new Print();

Comment: Programming tends to be a lot of tiny, time consuming problems.  3 hours is not much in that context.

Comment: Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen  thanks!!! i think, i need to study harder :)